# UEFI Secure Boot - VirtualBox - Ubuntu 14.02 and keyboard broken

Tags: boot, kernel, uefi

I have installed VirtualBox on my Ubuntu 16.04 and I get the problem about UEFI Boot Secure.

I have tried many answers here and I found one that can solve that, but my laptop keyboard is broken. I follow all the steps, when I reboot my laptop, I cannot perform the MOK Management because it does not recognize my external USB keyboard. I guess.

So any ideas how can I solve that without rebooting my laptop or another way to sign kernel modules?

Comment: Can you Paste "the problem about UEFI Boot Secure" you get or is that the actual error?

Comment: I can not load the virtualbox because its module is not signed.

Comment: So disable Secure Boot.

Comment: It's a option but I have dual boot.